# Problema con punteros y clases/objetos en C++

Tags: c++, punteros, diseño-de-clases

Se me pide que mi programa haga lo siguiente:

*Constructor paramétrico que recibe una cadena de C (const char *) y con ella inicializa el objeto.
Esta función debe determinar el tamaño de la cadena de C que recibe, y con esa información reservar un vector dinámico del tamaño correcto
para almacenar una copia de la cadena proporcionada como argumento.
Luego deberá hacer la copia y actualizar la variable m_size.
Una función de acceso size_t size() que regresa el tamaño de la cadena.
Una función char* cstr() que regresa un apuntador al primer caracter de la cadena.*

MI PROBLEMA es que m_str que es el puntero, al final del constructor parametrico lo regresé a la primera posicion de la cadena y el programa lo muestra correctamente, pero cuando quiero usar las funciones cstr o prueba que me impriman o regrese ese valor, el puntero tiene basura, no existe o no sé en dónde se encuentre pero no se encuentra en donde se supone que el contructor parametrico lo había dejado. Es más, es como si no existiera porque no me toma siquiera el cout. La función aplica al objeto, en este caso B que tiene la cadena "hola" por lo que tendría que tomar la información de B y con ello, su apuntador. ¿Por qué el apuntador nisiquiera sale y nisiquiera lo toma en cuenta fuera del constructor, pero cuando está dentro de el si? en cual si me marca cuando está en la primera posicion? Que puedo hacer para que las funciones me localicen correctamente al puntero y muestren su primera posicion?

EDIT: Estoy viendo que al final del ciclo de vida del constructor TODO se borra, cómo le hago para que la cadena creada, los punteros y la información se la pase a las funciones que estén trabajando con el objeto?

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

class CADENA{
private:
    size_t m_size;
    char* m_str;
    char* m_copia;
public:

    //Constructor por defecto //A
    CADENA(): m_size(0), m_str(nullptr){}

    //Constructor parametrico //B
    CADENA(const char * m_str){

        //Obtener tamanio de la cadena
            size_t contador=0;
            while(*m_str!='\0'){
                m_str++;
                contador++;
            }
            m_size = contador+1;

        //Crear vector dinamico
        m_copia = new char[m_size];
        m_str -= m_size-1;

        //Copiar el contenido de la cadena al nuevo vector
        for(int i=0; i<m_size-1;i++){
        *m_copia = *m_str;
        m_copia++;
        m_str++;
        }
        *m_copia = '\0';

    //Ciclo para regresar m_str a la primera posicion

    for(int i=m_size-1;i>0;i--){
    m_str--;
    }
    cout<<"Valor de m_str regresado al inicio: "<<*m_str<<endl;

    }

size_t Regresar();
char* cstr();
void prueba();

};

int main(){
CADENA A;
CADENA B("hola");
cout<<"\nTamanio de la cadena recibida A: "<<A.Regresar()<<endl;
cout<<"Tamanio de la cadena recibida B: "<<B.Regresar()<<endl;

cout<<"\nValor del puntero del objeto A: "<<A.cstr()<<endl;
cout<<"Valor del puntero del objeto B: "<<B.cstr()<<endl;
B.prueba();
return 0;
}


size_t CADENA::Regresar(){
return m_size;
}

char* CADENA::cstr(){
return m_str;
} 
void CADENA::prueba(){
cout<<"Valor del puntero m_str: "<<m_str;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes un parámetro que se llama igual que un miembro.

```
char* m_str

...

CADENA(const char * m_str)
```

Por lo tanto el puntero miembro nunca se asigna y una dirección de memoria desconocida.

Esto lo puedes solucionar cambiando el nombre, que por la forma en que lo escribiste, es probable que estés usando una nomenclatura dónde llevan el prefijo `m_` (de member).

Lo suyo sería que el parámetro del constructor se llame simplemente `str` o que lleve el prefijo `p_` (de parameter).

Si lo prefieres puedes acceder al miembro mediante [`this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this):

```
this->m_str = dirección;
```

---

Otras observaciones:

- No necesitas más de 2 miembros, solo `m_size` y `m_str`. Usa variables locales si necesitas guardar información temporal.
- Puedes usar las funciones que ya existen [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) y [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) para obtener la longitud de un string y copiarlo.
- Si decides reinventar la rueda, es aconsejable que pongas el código en nuevas funciones, pudiendo reutilizar el código con una simple llamada a la función correspondiente.
- No olvides liberar la memoria que asignas. El mejor lugar para hacerlo es en el [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor).
- Puedes usar carácteres del español en los comentarios, no necesitas evitarlos.

Comment: Por ejemplo si uso "this" dentro de una funcion aparte que me retorne el valor del puntero tendría ser return this? o tendria que usar this->m_str? Aun no estoy muy familiarizado con los punteros.

Comment: Si quieres devolver un miembro tienes que usar `this->` y el nombre del miembro. Es POO, similar a como lo harías en Java o C#. Solo que en el caso de C++ el `this` es un puntero que apunta a la instancia.